# Python: dataframe: I want to select or drop column contain Paid or Non-Paid

Tags: python, function, dataframe

I have a dataframe contain Names and Paid/Non-paid. I want to exclude those names, I already Paid in my dataframe.

```
df: 
1. Name, Paid/Non-paid
2. James, Paid
3. Alex, Non-paid
4. Apple, Paid
5. June, Non-paid
6. Kelly, Non-paid
```

This code 
`df[df.Paid/Non-paid.isin('Paid')]` gives error message

```
error msg: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Ad'
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it:

```
df[df["Paid/Non-paid"] != "Paid"]
```

The reason your code doesn't work is because pandas (or Python in general) doesn't support non alpha-numeric (and _) characters in variable names, and so you cannot use syntactic sugar for accessing column names which have these.